# jQuery .attr("src") for img not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This bugs the hell out of me.

```
<div id="HLrec_preview" style="width: 218px;">
    <img src="HLrec.jpg" style="width: 218px;">
<div style="font-weight: bold;" id="title">a</div>
<div id="link">a</div>
<div id="plaintext">a</div>
</div>
<script>
    var HL_rec_image_link = $("#HLrec_preview img").attr("src");
    alert(HL_rec_image_link);
</script>
```

Code works perfectly well in jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/t72uQ/

But on my website, it doesn't work. Alert shows up blank.

There must be something external that affects the result, but I can't figure out what.

What could be causing this?

Thanks in advance

More Complete Code:

```
<input type="button" id="HLrec_input" value="HL Recommends" style="display:block; width:222px;"/>
<div id="HLrec_preview" style="width: 218px;">
    <img src="" style="width: 218px;"/>
    <div style="font-weight: bold;" id="title"></div>
    <div id="link"></div>
    <div id="plaintext"></div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {

            var HLrec = "<?php 
    if(isset($_GET["ID"])) 
        echo $row["HL_REC"];
    else
        echo "0";
        ?>";
        if(HLrec == "1")
        {   
            <?php
        $query = "SELECT IMAGE_LINK, TITLE, LINK, PLAINTEXT FROM HL_Rec WHERE ID=" . $_GET['ID'];
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
            ?>

            $("#HLrec_preview img").attr('src', "<?php echo $row["IMAGE_LINK"]; ?>");   
            $("#HLrec_preview #title").text("<?php echo $row["TITLE"]; ?>");
            $("#HLrec_preview #link").text("<?php echo $row["LINK"]; ?>");
            $("#HLrec_preview #plaintext").text("<?php echo $row["PLAINTEXT"]; ?>");
        }

$("#submit_input").click(function(e) { 
            //set HLrec data
    var HL_rec = 0;
    var HL_rec_title = "none";
    var HL_rec_link = "none";
    var HL_rec_image_link = $("#HLrec_preview img").attr("src");
    var HL_rec_plaintxt = "none";
    alert(HL_rec_image_link);
    if(HL_rec_image_link.length > 0)
    {
        HL_rec = 1;
        HL_rec_title = $("#HLrec_preview #title").text();
        HL_rec_link = $("#HLrec_preview #link").text();
        HL_rec_image_link = $("#HLrec_preview img").attr('src');
        HL_rec_plaintxt = $("#HLrec_preview #plaintext").text();
    }
    else
        HL_rec_image_link = "none";
       });
});
</script>
```

More code!
This code changes the src from an iframe called in the page

```
//appends the article tags with content
var title = $("#title").val();
var url = $("#link").val();
var plaintxt = $("#plaintext").val();
//inject html
$("#HLrec_preview img", parent.document).attr('src', newfile);
$("#HLrec_preview #title", parent.document).text(title);
$("#HLrec_preview #link", parent.document).text(url);
$("#HLrec_preview #plaintext", parent.document).text(plaintxt);
```

WHOOPS.

Had another line of code that interfered.
Hate when that happens.

This is the bad code

```
//remove t variable from img src's to re enable caching
$("#content_reader_collumn img, #submit_form img").each(function(index, element) {
    $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").substring(0, $(this).attr("src").indexOf('?t=')));
});
```

just have to change the selector.

Thanks for the help guys

Comment: would you give us your website url?

Comment: Is the code inside the document ready handler?

Comment: yes, especially if you suspect that the issue isn't in the code you've already supplied.

Comment: I can't give you the website, sry. And yes the code inside a ready handler, hiding behind a submit handler. I need the src for a post form, but it's pulling it blank.

Comment: are there multiple #HLrec_preview on the page?

Comment: Did you add jquery library?

Comment: clear the browser cache? Look in the brower console for JS errors

Comment: What does the console Tell you (Methode `console.log`)?

Comment: Try looking at your dev tools for script errors if there's any. You can also breakpoint to trace your code.

Comment: yes, jquery lib is there, no, no other #HLrec_previews, console shows these "Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html:"

Comment: Is `$ro2` a typo in the original code?

Comment: yes, but it doesn't cause the issue.

Comment: In other words, that pulls in the src originally, the src is then later replaced from an iframe

Comment: That warning is caused by `src=""`, since it tries to load the current page as an image.

Comment: `echo $row["HL_REC"];` Must Produce `”1"` for the `src` Attribute to receive a value, have you ascertained that ?

Comment: the html code displayed is the code at the time of submission. src has a value

Comment: @Nikzilla: The html Sets `src` to the empty String, it`s the Jquery Code That Provides actually Content.

Comment: @Nikzilla can you show me the interpreted javascript code when you run it?

Comment: The Second Code snippet doesn't define `newfile`, is it assigned earlier ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem can be here

```
$("#HLrec_preview img").attr('src', "<?php echo $row["IMAGE_LINK"]; ?>");
```

Ty this instead

```
$("#HLrec_preview img").attr('src', "<?php echo $row['IMAGE_LINK']; ?>");
```

Similarly,

```
$("#HLrec_preview #title").text("<?php echo $row['TITLE']; ?>");
$("#HLrec_preview #link").text("<?php echo $row['LINK']; ?>");
$("#HLrec_preview #plaintext").text("<?php echo $row['PLAINTEXT']; ?>");
```

Disclaimer: I didn't test it.

Comment: PHP shouldn't care whether you use single or double quotes there.

Comment: Yes, that is an error, however it doesn't change the problem. That code only initializes the src on load, it is then later changed from an iframe. When I submit, I can actually see that the src is "HLrec.jpg".

Comment: @Barmar but wouldn't "<?php echo $row[" be considered as one string

Comment: @Nikzilla did you try this? `$("#HLrec_preview img").prop("src");`

Comment: No. The quotes that are before `<?php` are in HTML/Javascript, PHP ignores them.